# Create SEARCH and go through each result

Tags: vb.net, search, textbox, richtextbox

Basically I've got a RichTextBox, TextBox and a Button. The RichTextBox has some text in it and the Textbox is used to type the word and the button is used to find it. So far I'm using:

```
Dim index As Integer = 0
Dim temp As String = txtbx_Write.Text
txtbx_Write.Text = String.Empty
txtbx_Write.Text = temp

While index < txtbx_Write.Text.LastIndexOf(TextBox1.Text)
  txtbx_Write.Find(TextBox1.Text, index, txtbx_Write.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
  txtbx_Write.SelectionBackColor = Color.DarkGray
  index = txtbx_Write.Text.IndexOf(TextBox1.Text, index) + 1
End While
```

Basically what this does is that when I type e.g. "The", if there is "The" in the RichTextBox, it will set a background colour for that word and it will do it for each "The" word.

What I would like to do is that, When I type in the word "The", there will be a label with the amount of results there is and for each time the user clicks the "Find" button, it will select the word "The" and keep selecting and going until there isn't any more.

Pretty much like the native Notepad find feature where it selects and goes through each word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to do with that temp variable... and you might want to write something to clear the background color when you're done.

Anyway, you could do the following for your "find" button:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Not RichTextBox1.Focused Then
        RichTextBox1.Focus()
    End If
    RichTextBox1.Find(TextBox1.Text, RichTextBox1.SelectionStart + RichTextBox1.SelectionLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
End Sub
```

Read about Find method in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.

edit: In order to find the amount of hit results, you may simply count the "highlighting" while loop. Because you have to go through all the words to highlight them the information is already there.

Sample code:

```
Dim index As Integer = 0
Dim count As Integer = 0
While index < RichTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(TextBox1.Text)        
    RichTextBox1.Find(TextBox1.Text,index,RichTextBox1.TextLength, 
                      RichTextBoxFinds.None)
    RichTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.DarkGray
    index = RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(TextBox1.Text, index) + 1
    count = count + 1
End While
```

And count will hold the result amount.

Comment: Thank You! ONE more thing, how can I get the amount of results e.g.  in the sentence "Yes No No Then No Yes" there are 3 "No" how can i get the 3? like the count of the word when I type in "No" and search for it?

Comment: @F4z see my edit. you might want to read about while loops if you're planning to do more programming in the future.